# Setting the JS dropdown selection checkmark in an appropriate position and make dropdown list look better

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement a dropdown/selection list in JS and here is what I have written:

```
//some js code

#startJobDialog (A dialog box in JS)

// js code


var markUp = "<ul id='topMenu' class='ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content' role='menu' tabindex='0' style='display: table; width: 220px; margin: 0 auto;'>\r\n";
  markUp += "\t<li data-menu='job' class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-2' tabindex='2' role'=menuitem' style='display: inline-block; width: 220px; vertical-align: top; horizontal-align: center'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s'></span>\r\n";
  markUp += "<ul class='subMenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content' id='jobMenu' role='menu' tabindex='-1' style='display: block; padding-left: 40px;'><li class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-5' tabindex='0' role='menuitem'><br></br>-->Tier1 VAE<br></br></li > <li class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-6' tabindex='1' role='menuitem'>-->Tier1 Non-VAE<br></br></li><li class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-7' tabindex='2' role='menuitem'>-->Tier2<br></br></li><li class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-7' tabindex='3' role='menuitem'>-->Tier1 Smart Conversion<br></br></li></ul></li>\r\n";

  $("#startJobDialog").html(markUp);

...
```

As per above code, I am setting HTML `markup` to `#startJobDialog` and it gives me following output:

[image: JS output]

As you can see, whenever I select an item in the menu list, the `selection checkmark` is coming below the selected item, but I really want it to be next to the item selected. It looks like the width is correct and I tried tweaking it. Not a JS expert, I am in initial exercises - any insights on different class, styles, and other parameters with respect to `<ul>, <li>`, etc. would help and I really want to make this dropdown look better than it is right now.

How to set that checkmark in the right/my desired position in JS and make the selection list look better?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a JS issue. You just need to figure out what the correct HTML and CSS is, then make the JS produce that.

Comment: what do you mean by "produce" you JS - what parameters do I need to look at

Comment: You're just creating the HTML as a string. Figure out what the HTML should be, and put that into the string.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to remove the css from your markup and put them in a css file.

From there, try absolute positioning your elements.

I have provided an example snippet of your code in this post, just to look at and play around with.  You can see a bunch of `<br>`'s being added to what I would assume is the default selected item.  I don't see where the checkmark is being added.

If you provide a snippet, I can help you further.  But, floating, or absolute positioning could be an option.  Or you can use the ::before or ::after pseudo selectors.

In order for me to be more specific I would need to see the exact markup that gets generated.

```js
var markUp = "<ul id='topMenu' class='ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content' role='menu' tabindex='0' style='display: table; width: 220px; margin: 0 auto;'>\r\n";
  markUp += "\t<li data-menu='job' class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-2' tabindex='2' role'=menuitem' style='display: inline-block; width: 220px; vertical-align: top; horizontal-align: center'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s'></span>\r\n";
  markUp += "<ul class='subMenu ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content' id='jobMenu' role='menu' tabindex='-1' style='display: block; padding-left: 40px;'><li class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-5' tabindex='0' role='menuitem'><br></br>-->Tier1 VAE<br></br></li > <li class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-6' tabindex='1' role='menuitem'>-->Tier1 Non-VAE<br></br></li><li class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-7' tabindex='2' role='menuitem'>-->Tier2<br></br></li><li class='ui-menu-item' id='ui-id-7' tabindex='3' role='menuitem'>-->Tier1 Smart Conversion<br></br></li></ul></li>\r\n";

  $("#startJobDialog").html(markUp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="startJobDialog"></div>
```

Comment: lets chat and I can show the markup or the tool that I am using and trying to apply above JS script. Can you invite me? I need to share the login info of the account

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get this until now.  Do you still need help with this?  What do you want me to invite you to?